# AngularJs: Calling contoller method from directive inside another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive inside another directive. Outer directive shares its scope with controller, while inner one has its own. I'd like to pass a reference to controller's function to inner directive so it can be called from there. But I cannot figure out how to pass the function and its parameters to inner directive so it can properly call the controller's function.

Here is [planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TWrPM2kU5KRPDtNgZ1rp?p=preview) to illustrate my problem.

If you click on "Dir 2 Click me" the alert says the parameters have came undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the outer controller method using `'='` and adjust the code accordingly...

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.myCtrlMethod = function(msg, b) {
            alert(msg + ' and b='+b);
        };
    })
    .directive('dir1', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<div><p ng-click="myDir1Method(\'my dir1 method\',\'b\')">Dir 1 Click me</p><dir2 my-ctrl-method="myCtrlMethod"></dir2></div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                scope.myDir1Method = function(msg,b){
                    scope.myCtrlMethod(msg, b);
                };
            }
        };
    }])
    .directive('dir2', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                myCtrlMethod: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            template: '<p ng-click="myDir2Method(\'my dir2 method\',\'b\')">Dir 2 Click me</p>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                scope.myDir2Method = function(msg,b){
                    scope.myCtrlMethod(msg, b);
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xbSNXaSmzWa3G1GSH6Af?p=preview

Edit: `'='` evaluates the expression in the context of the parent scope and its result is bound to the property on the inner scope. In this example, 'myCtrlMethod' is evaluated against the parent scope, which returns `myCtrlMethod` from the parent scope (a function). This function is bound to `myCtrlMethod` on the inner scope, and can be invoked with `scope.myCtrlMethod(msg, b)`.

Comment: It does work, thank you very much! But I've thought the '=' is used for binding to outer scope's properties. Could you give a short explanation or provide a link why this works?

Comment: No problem... The different ways to bind the variables are indeed confusing. Updated with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you can use controller as a reference to your directive

See: http://jsbin.com/vayij/1/edit

```
directive('sonDirective', function(){
  return {
         restrict: 'E'
         scope: {},
         replace: true,
         template: '<div....'
         controller: 'MainController' //controller as a reference 
      }
})
```

Comment: Your example works fine. But when I've modified the jsbin to match my example it's stopped working. http://jsbin.com/caxoheno/2/edit

Comment: try this out : http://jsbin.com/caxoheno/3/edit,
the problem is, that it's not a global function, it's key under your controller scope.
use $scope.yourMethod, or use Ctrl as Ctrl and get access from the DOM

Comment: It's another approach to resolve my issue. Unfortunately, I cannot have two accepted answers and the first one suits me better. Thanks a bunch anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the controller on the scope : `$scope.$b=this;`

See : http://plnkr.co/edit/skDF8D1scFJYrTUmcXIL?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. When I click on "Dir 2 Click me" it still shows **msg** parameter as undefined.